# Access modifier location explanation in scala

Tags: scala

I discovered that we can use access modifier before class  as well as after class name. For example, I have 2 classes as follows

```
package com.company.package.sub_package

protected class Animal1{
  def makeSound(): Unit = println("Bow ow")
}


object Animal1{
  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    val animal = new Animal2()
    animal.makeSound()
  }
}
```

```
package com.company.package.sub_package

class Animal2 protected{
  def makeSound(): Unit = println("Meow")
}


object Animal2{
  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    val animal = new Animal1()
    animal.makeSound()
  }
}
```

Here an error shows up in Animal1 main method saying Animal2 cannot be accessed in object Animal1.

If I extend Animal2 class, the sub class is able to access the parent class.

What I understand from this is if we write protected after the class name, it is not available to classes in same package and if I right it before class, it is available to all classes in the package, only to its sub classes, is this a correct assumption? What is the exact significance of location of an access modifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the exact significance of location of an access modifier?

The access modifier *always* comes before the thing whose access it modifies.

In your first example, `protected` comes before the class `Animal1`, so it regulates access to the class.

In your second example, `protected` comes before the primary constructor, so it regulates access to the primary constructor. (Note: it's not obvious that it comes before the primary constructor because `Animal2` has an empty primary constructor, but the Scala Language Specification says that if there is no parameter list for a class, an empty `()` parameter list is inserted.)

So, your `Animal2` class is actually equivalent to

```scala
class Animal2 protected () {
  def makeSound(): Unit = println("Meow")
}
```

A typical reason for restricting access to the primary constructor is to control instance creation either through auxiliary constructors or factory methods in the companion module.

You can find the specification for access modifiers of the primary constructor in [section 5.3 *Class Definitions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-definitions) of the Scala Language Specification.

Answer (score 3):

The access modified before a `class` is like the access modifier for any other value in a class. It specifies the visibility of that class outside the containing class and in subclasses.

The access modifier after the `class` applies to the constructor and specifies the visibility of the constructor outside *the companion object for that class*

Typically it is used to hide the default constructor:

```
class Positive private(val i: Int)

object Positive {
  def apply(i: Int): Positive = new Positive(math.abs(i))
}
```

You can access the `i` field of a `Positive` but it can never be negative.